# joomla menu not vertically aligning icons

Tags: joomla

Hi I am struggling with a joomla application that I am currently writing.

I am using Joomla 3.3 and in this instance I am using the icons that come with the menu, the text for the menu is vertically aligned (correct) but the images are top aligned.

I have tried to google the problem with little success and just wondered if anyone knew how to solve, screenshot attached.

http://www.prntscr.com/63c5x96zp.jpg

Comment: deleted my answer. The link you provided links to "Lightshot" which initially I thought was your website but it isn't. Please provide a link to your own website as a screenshot doesn't allow us to help you

Comment: www.imsdrive.co.uk, the main icons are on a private menu requiring login, but I have put one icon on the main public menu

Comment: In which case, make the images temporarily public or provide some code

Comment: have a look at the url now, i have added one icon on public menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.desktop ul.art-hmenu > li.ext > a img, 
.desktop ul.art-hmenu > li.ext > ul > li > a img {
    vertical-align: middle
}
```

Comment: Thanks where will I find that

Comment: Thanks this is the css code I have found, what do i add...table, ul.art-hmenu
{
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', Arial, 'Arial Unicode MS', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;

Comment: Sorry, had a meet at work so no time to add an explanation. Glad you finally got it working

Comment: Hi yes it did sort of work, but only aligns when there are sub-menu items for that item

Comment: @JonathanGreen - I've updated the code according to your needs. Will work for all menu items now ;)

Comment: Thanks that has now vertically aligned all parent menu items, however still doesnt affect the submenu, see screenshot.  prntscr.com/63taal

Comment: made no difference i'm afraid, sub menu still top aliging icon see prntscr.com/63to8e

Comment: Can you make one of the submenu items with an image visible to the public please.

Comment: Sure go to www.imsdrive.co.uk you will see the sample here prntscr.com/63ts2t

Comment: Thanks that's done it, will that word for the next level down too, ie the a sub item of a subitem

Comment: LOL its close enough, it aligns parent menu icons and submenu icons, but only does parent item alignment if there is a child menu, see screenshot, in my case there will be a child item in every case so its ok, thank you for your help prntscr.com/63umq4